# CreateJS / Adobe Animate CC: testing a simple function

Tags: javascript, createjs

I'm trying to test run a simple function that's declared in the first frame. When I write `fl_DoRestart();` on `frame 50`  I get the following error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: fl_DoRestart is not defined`, but it's defined on frame one. Why's this not working? This used to be very simple in actionscript :(

I eventually need to be able to call this function from another function, right now I'm just testing it.

Here's my function on frame one:

```
function fl_DoRestart(){
        this.gotoAndPlay(1);
        console.log("play From Start");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function has been defined on that frame, but it has no reference to anything. You can call it from that frame script only (and `this` may be `window` instead of that script)

With Animate export, it is recommended to store method calls on `this`, so they can be accessed.

```
this.fl_DoRestart(){
    this.gotoAndPlay(1);
    console.log("play From Start");
}
this.fl_DoRestart();

// From the root
exportRoot.someMoveClip.fl_DoRestart();

// Using a callback
btn.addEventListener("click", someMovieClip.fl_DoRestart.bind(this));

// Shortcut with "on()"
btn.on("click", someMovieClip.fl_DoRestart, this);
```

Hope that sheds some light on how this works. One additional thing to consider is that frame scripts in Animate CC export will run each time that frame is accessed, so you may want to check if things are defined before running scripts.

```
if (this.fl_DoRestart == null) {
   // Then define stuff here
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Lanny this is helpful. So if I use `this` in declaring the function, I can then access that function from other frames? Otherwise functions scope is limited to the frame they were declared on?

And the function will just run if declared but not called? Wow! 

Ok thanks I have some more things to play round with here :)