# CreateJS targeting mc scope issue

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, createjs, animate-cc

In Adobe AnimateCC using CreateJS I have an mc on frame one called `disclaimer_btn`, and an mc on frame one called `discTxt`. I want to be able to mouseover `disclaimer_btn` and gotoAndStop on a frame label in `discTxt`. Round about frame 150 I try to do the mouseover and it's not working. If I use an alert box in my function, that works.

The error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined` and in the code it points to here `.bind(this));`

If I remove `this.discTxt` from before `this.discTxt.fl_MouseOverHandler.bind(this));` I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: fl_MouseOverHandler is not defined`.

I have read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638757/how-to-target-a-movieclip-with-createjs) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257022/createjs-adobe-animate-cc-testing-a-simple-function) and those solutions are not working for me in this case.

I get this is a problem of scope, what am I doing wrong here?

```
var frequency = 3;
stage.enableMouseOver(frequency);
this.disclaimer_btn.addEventListener("mouseover", this.discTxt.fl_MouseOverHandler.bind(this));

this.fl_MouseOverHandler = function()
{
    this.discTxt.gotoAndStop("on");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a problem with the order. Because you have to define the function as a variable on `this`, the function definition is not 'hoisted". Hoisted functions get defined first, no matter the order they are defined in the code.

```
// Hoisted
function myFunction() {}

// Not hoisted
var myFunction = function() {}
this.myFunction = function() {}
```

In the second example, the variable itself is defined, but it will be null until the line where you set it. You can fix this by moving the `addEventListener` to below that line so it is called after the function is defined.

Alternatively, change to a hosted method, and bind that:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", myFunction.bind(this));
function myFunction() {}
```

You can also use `on`, which is a CreateJS function replacement for `addEventListener`, which has some syntactic sugar, such as a scope parameter.

```
btn.on("click", myFunction, this);
```

Lastly, if you do define the function using `this`, ensure you pass the right value. In your example, you define the function on `this`, but pass it as a property of `this.discTxt`. Unless `this.discTxt` is another MovieClip, and the function is defined there instead, you will be passing null.

TLDR:

- If you define the function as a property on `this`, then move it below the `addEventListener
- OR change it so the function is defined using `function myFunction()`, and bind it.